# Render SwiftUI view to pdf ( debug Errors)

Tags: swiftui

I use this method for render a SwiftUI view to a PDF, My method is work and my app not crashing but I got errors on the debug area. The errors appearing exactly when I tap ShareLink button.

my code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View { ...
        // Rest of the codes
        
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItemGroup {
                ShareLink("Export PDF", item: render())
            }
        }
    }
    
    func render() -> URL {
        // 1: Render Hello World with some modifiers
        let renderer = ImageRenderer(content: PdfView)
        
        
        // 2: Save it to our documents directory
        let url = URL.documentsDirectory.appending(path: "test.pdf")
        
        // 3: Start the rendering process
        renderer.render { size, context in
            // 4: Tell SwiftUI our PDF should be the same size as the views we're rendering
            var box = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
            
            // 5: Create the CGContext for our PDF pages
            guard let pdf = CGContext(url as CFURL, mediaBox: &box, nil) else {
                return
            }
            
            // 6: Start a new PDF page
            pdf.beginPDFPage(nil)
            
            // 7: Render the SwiftUI view data onto the page
            context(pdf)
            
            // 8: End the page and close the file
            pdf.endPDFPage()
            pdf.closePDF()
        }
        
        return url
    }
    
var PdfView: some View { ...
        // Rest of the code
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

How I can solve that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your sharing issue, you can try getting the documents url as follows rather:

```
let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
```

And then creating a directory:

```
try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: url.path, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
```

Also, it seems like you need to annotate your `render` function as `@MainActor`. You make use of an `ImageRenderer` function that is annotated by `@MainActor`, telling it to run on the main thread.

Full example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        // Rest of the codes
        
        EmptyView()
            .navigationTitle("")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItemGroup {
                    ShareLink("Export PDF", item: render())
                }
            }
    }
    
    @MainActor func render() -> URL {
        // 1: Render Hello World with some modifiers
        let renderer = ImageRenderer(content: PdfView)
        
        
        // 2: Save it to our documents directory
        let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
        let url = documentsURL.appending(path: "test.pdf")

        do {
            try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: url.path, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            NSLog("Unable to create directory \(error.debugDescription)")
        }
        
        // 3: Start the rendering process
        renderer.render { size, context in
            // 4: Tell SwiftUI our PDF should be the same size as the views we're rendering
            var box = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
            
            // 5: Create the CGContext for our PDF pages
            guard let pdf = CGContext(url as CFURL, mediaBox: &box, nil) else {
                return
            }
            
            // 6: Start a new PDF page
            pdf.beginPDFPage(nil)
            
            // 7: Render the SwiftUI view data onto the page
            context(pdf)
            
            // 8: End the page and close the file
            pdf.endPDFPage()
            pdf.closePDF()
        }
        
        return url
    }
    
    var PdfView: some View {
        // Rest of the code
        EmptyView()
    }
}
```

When checking out your code I got the following compiler errors:

- `Call to main actor-isolated initializer 'init(content:)' in a synchronous nonisolated context`
- `Call to main actor-isolated instance method 'render(rasterizationScale:renderer:)' in a synchronous nonisolated context`

You can also command click on `ImageRenderer`'s `render()` to see the following information:

In your code:

```
// 3: Start the rendering process
        renderer.render { size, context in
```

It will open up:

[image]

Here you can see that the function you use in the image rendering library is marked as `@MainActor`.

Some useful links:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/mainactor

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/concurrency/how-to-use-mainactor-to-run-code-on-the-main-queue